# Java How To Check If Node In Tree Is Selected?

Tags: java, jtree

i have a JTree in Java with different parent nodes such as computers, gaming systems, tv's, and networking equipment, with my root node being "technology" what i wanted to    do was, whenever a user clicks on one of the nodes (for example under the gaming systems node i have xbox360 and ps3) so if the user where to click on ps3, a web browser would pop up, taking them to the ps3 main website. I know how to do that with the Desktop class in java, but i am unsure as to how i can check if the node has been selected, or if a mouse click has been released, since nodes do not offer MouseListeners or such. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JTree responds to the [TreeSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) rather than the MouseListener. Try [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) for some examples.